# TRY CATCH THROWS exception without logging

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exception

I am looking through someone elses code and there is plenty of code like this:

```
try
   'Logic here
catch e as exception
throw
end try
```

I believe that the TRY and CATCH cause are pointless (they were probably used for debugging).  Is there ever a scenario were coding like this is good practice?

There is a global even handler (global.asa).

Comment: Maybe as placeholder for a logging functionality that obviously never was implemented. So at least it caused you to think about it which is good.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter,thanks.  Do you suggest removing them or leaving them?

Comment: I would think about it and remove it once you know that either it's not possible anymore that an exception will be raised or you want to handle it at a global exception handler. But you should consider to add a readable error-message by providing a new exception type and add this original exception as `InnerException`. Then throw the new exception instead.

Comment: This is mostly a pattern of people who haven't fully grasped the concept yet.

Comment: Are there any comments in the `Catch` block that might explain why the exception is being rethrown?

Answer (score 3):

I agree that these clauses are pointless and worse, add clutter to your code that adds nothing other than confusion.

Worse still: if they ever do `Throw e` instead of just `Throw` the stack on the original exception is lost.

Comment: This is a commonly accepted opinion, but i'm not convinced of it. Often  it is better to know that a code block can throw an exception even if the exception is not handled at all. Maybe it's not that obvious and good to know that you should keep an eye on the implementation or at least implement logging functionality with a readable error message.

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no reason to have a try..catch that only throws. If you want to debug and catch exceptions at the moment they occur, you should  halt on framework exceptions within Visual Studio (Debug menu -> Exceptions...).

Comment: I almost upvoted this, but I disagree slightly.  It should say, "There is rarely a good reason to have a `Try/Catch` that only throws."  I agree that generally, you don't want to do this, however.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin In what scenario, would you ever want to only throw? Throwing a new exception is different, but having a catch with only a throw is no different than the try..catch being missing.

Comment: I can't really think of any situations I would want to do this.  Doesn't mean that such a situation doesn't exist, though.  I am really just playing "devil's advocate" here and thinking of some theoretical scenario where it might be okay to do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same thing in one of the programs I inherited and it's actually *worse* because catching is expensive in C# (only trying is free). I made it a point to remove a dozen of these every day, I should be done in a few more weeks.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. The catch block is not empty, so the exception will be triggered the same way as if there was no catch at all. Why do you assume that an exception is raised at all?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think @Blindy means that Rethrowing is expensive, assuming that an exception ever occurs in the first place.  If this is a code block where an exception cannot occur, then the `Try/Catch` is pointless and only serves to clutter up the code.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin: to quote [J. Skeet](http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/exceptions2.html): "If you ever get to the point where exceptions are significantly hurting your performance, you have problems in terms of your use of exceptions beyond just the performance."

Comment: @TimSchmelter I can agree with that.  I think that if you are throwing an exception, performance is probably the least of your worries.  I was just trying to elaborate on what I think Blindy was trying to say.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, well if OP's case is anything like mine and *every single god damn function* had a `try..catch` block that did nothing, they can add up pretty fast.

Comment: @blindy: the try-catch itself doesnt cost anything in terms of performance.

Answer (score -1):

Generally, you don't want to do this (and you don't want to catch `System.Exception` either).

That being said, there might be some cases where you want to `Throw` the exception further up the call stack, and `Catch` it elsewhere.  Here is a trivial example:

```
Try
   ' Do some stuff here.  For this example, let's assume 
   ' it cannot cause any exceptions       
   Try
       ' Do some other stuff here that CAN cause an exception
   Catch innerEx as Exception
       ' Rethrowing so that the outer block handles this
       Throw
   End Try
Catch ex as Exception
   MessageBox.Show("I just caught an exception.")
End Try
```

IF you do something like this, common sense dictates that you should place a comment that states WHY you are doing this.

As I said, that is an overly trivial example, but a more common usage might be that you have a method that calls another method, and you want the first method to handle any exceptions that the 2nd method might throw.  The behavior will be the same if you leave the `Try/Catch` block out of the 2nd method instead of rethrowing, but the `Try/Catch` and the comment make your intent a little more obvious.

EDIT:  If you know which line of code is likely to throw the exception, then putting a comment above that line is probably preferable to adding the `Try/Catch` blocks.

Comment: Getting rid of the inner try..catch and the behavior doesn't change at all. So what's the point?

Comment: The behavior does not change, as I stated in the post.  The point is that the intent is a little more obvious, especially when there is a comment present.  It may make it slightly easier to follow, that's all I was saying.  In all fairness, a well-placed comment immediately above the code you expect to cause the exception would do the same thing without the need for `Try/Catch`.  Of course, that assumes that you know which code is likely to raise the exception to begin with.

Comment: This is exactly what the guy who wrote this at work said, "I know it does nothing, but it makes it clearer". He's been since let go.

Comment: @blindy The downvote was a little bit unnecessary.  I specifically stated that you typically don't want to do this, but here is a reason why somebody might do it anyways.  Never did I say that you SHOULD do this (although it doesn't really hurt anything other than cluttering up the code).